# How to find all Outlook calendars you have permission set-up for?

Tags: vba, outlook, exchange-server

I visited a remote site the other day where I will be seeing people at in the future. While there I had a user choose "SITEX - CONSULT ROOM 1" Calendar, right click and go into to the Calendar properties --> Permission --> Add .. and add my name as an Owner.

Now returning to my own machine and Outlook it doesn't seem to come up, and I cannot seem to work out the name when searching for it.

Is there any way in VBA to search Exchange server for the Calendar(s) shared to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can get a list of mailboxes to which you have delegate access (that information is stored in the AD and is accessible through the Extended MAPI or Redemption), but per-folder access rights are stored on the folder itself. There is no master list.